# Squashed unicode heavy check mark in Consolas Mintty

Tags: fonts, unicode, mintty

I use git bash prompt which uses the heavy check mark (`U+2714`), however using the Consolas font in Mintty the symbol appears squashed. The regular check mark (`U+2713`) appears normally.

I've tried adding `Charwidth=unicode` in my `.minttyrc` but it didn't help.

Here is what the regular check mark looks like:

[image: Regular check mark]

Here is what the heavy check mark looks like:

[image: Heavy check mark]

Any suggestions for how to get it to display normally? I would prefer not to switch to another font.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was introduced in Mintty 3.0.2 due to a fix for glyphs that were too wide, which consequently lead to this issue.

Reverting to Mintty 3.0.1 worked as a temporary fix, and a long term solution for the underlying issue is being discussed here: https://github.com/mintty/mintty/issues/892